# Find file matching extension, then count files in the found directory

Tags: linux, find

I am trying to search the filesystem for all files matching an extention (`*.what`), then count all files in the directory where it found the `*.what` files. The output should contain the directory name and filenames with count.

How can this be done?

Comment: cd /folder
find -name *.extension
this will list all files with the extension

Answer (score 4):

First you would use the `find` command in the terminal.

`find . -type f -name "*.what"`

That will list all files on the system from the current directory "." matching "type: file" and name "*.what".

So you can incorporate that into a bash script, like so:

**Edit**

Here you go, this does what you want I think.

```
#!/bin/bash

src=${1:-"."}
ext=${2:-"what"}

for dir in `find ${src} -type f -name "*.${ext}"`; do
    dir=`echo ${dir} | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{$NF=""}{print}'`
    echo ${dir} "has" `ls -l ${dir} | awk '!NR=1 && !/^d/ && !/*.what/ {print $NF}' | wc -l` "file(s)"
done
```

That will output the number of files in any directories that contain *.what (recursively).  The number if files excludes directories `!/^d/` and the *.what file `!/*.what/`.

That should get you there.  Works on my system at least, assuming I understand the question.

Comment: hmm, something not working quite right, the script only outputs 1 file found then ends. Its not searching through all the directories and subdirectories. Just to reiterate, I want to find any file ending with *.what and then count the number of all files in that same directory, not just counting the *.what files in the pwd.

Comment: That's because I misunderstood, it is currently just counting the number of *.what 's.  I will update in a few.

Comment: @Cyw updated above^^

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looking better, I'm still not getting the results and am getting error "awk: xregcomp: Invalid preceding regular expression" Could be due to its VMware ESXi 5.x system running AWK from BusyBox v1.9.1-VMware-visor-8630 (2012-01-06 01:09:05 PST) multi-call binary ??

Comment: Yeah, awk may behave differently under busybox.  Try breaking it down to see which it is, or both uses.

Comment: @Cyw - Have you tried my suggestion of testing awk in both uses to see if it is one or the other (or both)?  I am happy to try and find another option after knowing the limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pipeline:

```
find -name '*.what' -exec dirname {} \; | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: I need this to count the files in any directory where a *.what file is found and if the count is less than some #, display the pwd and filename and total file count within that directory. This needs to be a recursive search. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tmp/example.awk
{
   a[$1]++
} END {
   for (i in a) {
     dir=i; gsub(" ", "\\ ", dir) ;
     printf "echo %s: %d; cd %s; ls -1 *htm; cd ->/dev/null; echo\n", \
        i, a[i], dir, dir
   }
}
```

Sample output:

```
find . -iname "*.htm" -printf "%h\t%f\n" |sort |\
    awk -F'\t' -f tmp/example.awk |sh
```

```
(...)
./fpsu/applikasjon/kjerne/lib: 1
xom-1.0b5.htm

./tmp/refcp/refcp/home/jaroslav/reference/programing/input-processing: 1
Capitalizing+personal+names.htm

./Downloads/index files: 3
allclasses-frame.htm
overview-frame.htm
overview-summary.htm

./tmp/refcp/refcp/home/jaroslav/reference/code/html-css/common-web-fonts_files: 6
hostedbadge_002.htm
hostedbadge_003.htm
hostedbadge.htm
like_002.htm
like_003.htm
like.htm
(...)
```

The first step is to print every folder and file name with a given extension. That is accomplished with the %h %t arguments to find's printf.

The next step is to count every entry in a given folder with a[$1]++ in the awk program. That is, for every line printed, we increment an array entry with the index equal to the name of the directory found containing files with the given suffix.

When all entries have been counted we echo a simple shell command to print the results and list the files in every directory that we found.

The result is a list of shell commands that we pipe into `sh`.

Answer (score -1):

```
find -name *.c|grep -c .c
```

this will find the number of items with extension .c

```
find -name *.c
```

will list the directory structure of items with extension .c

```
!/bin/bash

find -name *$1|grep -c $1
find -name *$1
```

save this as list.sh in /home/yourname/bin

```
Chmod +x list.sh
chown {username} list.sh
```

call it anywhere by list *.extension

Example `list *.c`

Comment: I like this one.  But you need to make @cYrus's suggestion.

Comment: You should quote `*.c`.

Comment: using ubuntu it worked with out the quote ..

Simple script

`#!/bin/bash

find -name *$1|grep -c $1
find -name *$1`

Comment: Updated the answer simple way

Comment: This is good start but I need a way to count all files in any directory that a file with *.what is found and display the filename & directory name and  the total file count within that directory that the *.what file is found